# Клавиатура наезжает на RecyclerView

Tags: recyclerview, android-edittext, клавиатура

Использую `RecyclerView`.
Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на `EditText` клавиатура наезжает на `RecyclerView`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии клавиатуры `RecyclerView` прокручивался на ее величину, чтобы было вот так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как оказалось, я плохо искал. решение нашел в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102741/recyclerview-not-scrolling-to-end-when-keyboard-opens) посте.

В моем случае код выглядит так:

```
rvPrivateMessaging.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            if (bottom < oldBottom){
                rvPrivateMessaging.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        rvPrivateMessaging.scrollToPosition(
                                rvPrivateMessaging.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
```